# Node Js run real browser and connect to it

Tags: node.js, async-await

I wanna connect to chrome via sockets and then get some info from it

```
async function runRealBrowser() {
  await exec('google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222')
  let res = execSync('curl http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version').toString()
  res = JSON.parse(res)
  if (res && res.webSocketDebuggerUrl) {
  }
}
(async () => {
  await runRealBrowser()
})();
```

I use this piece of code to do it. The browser opens well every time, but the second call sometimes fails `Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9222: Connection refused`
I think the problem is in async calls, but can't catch it. Please any suggestions

Comment: This is a workaround of course, but have you considered using instead a headless browser such as  [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)?

Comment: I know about puppeter and playwright, but need real browser

Comment: Puppeteer is using the local Chrome installation, as I recall. It can also open it physically and drive it like you would.

Comment: Also, just to be absolutely sure, try `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: As I said above, it's random, so have the same situation for localhost

Comment: Then perhaps try some more baked in solution like axios

Comment: Karma? Selenium web driver?

Comment: Probably selenium.. I guess with karma you would have to run everything in the browser